# MongoDB retrive max value from different fields

Tags: mongodb, max

What is the way to retrieve maximum (or minimum) value of different fields for each document?

The collection is look like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "AQ",
    "arr_delay" : 262421.0,
    "carrier_delay" : 144922.0,
    "weather_delay" : 2297.0,
    "nas_delay" : 15933.0,
    "security_delay" : 1871.0,
    "late_aircraft_delay" : 97398.0
}
{
    ...
}
```

For each document in the collection I need to find the field with the minimum value compared to the other fields in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) and iterate over the docs keys like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      minField: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
              },
              as: "field",
              cond: {
                "$setIsSubset": [
                  [
                    {
                      $type: "$$field.v"
                    }
                  ],
                  [
                    "double",
                    "decimel",
                    
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          initialValue: {
            name: null,
            minVal: null
          },
          in: {
            name: {
              $cond: [
                {
                  $lt: [
                    "$$this.v",
                    "$$value.minVal"
                  ]
                },
                "$$this.k",
                "$$value.name"
              ]
            },
            minVal: {
              $min: [
                "$$this.v",
                "$$value.minVal"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "minField": "$minField.name"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rcyLxHYeALH)

If you're using Mongo v4.4+ you can also use [$isNumber](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/isNumber/) instead of the messy part of the `$filter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

- `$project` `fields` to create a array of fields

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      fields: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
```

- `$unwind` deconstruct `fields` array

```
  { $unwind: "$fields" },
```

- `$match` don't include `_id` field, you can add more fields if you want to remove from this comparison

```
  {
    $match: {
      "fields.k": { $ne: "_id" }
    }
  },
```

- `$group` by `_id`
- `$max` to get max from `fields` in maxValue
- `$min` to get min from `fields` in minValue

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      maxValue: { $max: "$fields.v" },
      minValue: { $min: "$fields.v" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qXQtnN8mm4h)